# Logic Error for Quiz in Java

Tags: java

My program does not have any Syntax errors but logic. The output should show if it is correct or incorrect for each question, and show how many
the quiz taker gets correct and how many incorrect at the end of the quiz.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SubtractionQuiz { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    //Declare and initialize variables
    final int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 10;
    int correctCount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int incorrect = 0;
    int temp;        
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (count < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS) {
      // Declare and initialize two random numbers
      int number1 = (int)(Math.random()*10);
      int number2 = (int)(Math.random()*10);

      if (number1 < number2) { 
        temp = number1;
        number1 = number2;
        number2 = temp;              
        // Prompt the question 
        System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " - " + number2 + "? ");
        int answer = input.nextInt();             

        if (number1 - number2 == answer) 
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            correctCount++;                
         } 
         else 
            System.out.println("Incorrect");
            incorrect++;
            count++;                             
        }
        System.out.printf("You got %d correct and %d incorrect!", correctCount, incorrect);    
       }       
    }
```

Comment: Take the [tour], read [MCVE]. Also, upvoter, explain your reasoning.

Comment: Suggest you try debugging it.

Comment: What happens if number2 >= number1 ? Is there a {} for that?

Comment: Make sure you have opening brackets (`{`) for all those closing ones.

Comment: Debug this stuff once and you will get it. It is way more effective than asking the SO community for each and every single problem.

Comment: What does it do wrong? What input data, what is the result, what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, your braces look off. Without an opening brace only the first line after an `if` or `else` is part of the conditional.

```
 if (number1 - number2 == answer)   // <--- should there be a "{" here?
   System.out.println("Correct!");
   correctCount++;

     } 
     else // <--- need a  "{" here ?
        System.out.println("Incorrect");
        incorrect++;
        count++;


    }
```

Suggest cleaning up your indentation to be consistent so you can more clearly see this issue.

Comment: When I add the curly braces you suggested it shows an error on line 46

Answer (score 0):

You have not added opening braces for the if and else blocks (containing more than 1 statement), also you will have to refactor the code a little.
Find my additions in the comments of this program

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SubtractionQuiz { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    //Declare and initialize variables
    final int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 10;
    int correctCount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int incorrect = 0;
    int temp;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (count < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS) {
      // Declare and initialize two random numbers
      int number1 = (int)(Math.random()*10);
      int number2 = (int)(Math.random()*10);

      if (number1<number2) { 
        temp = number1;
        number1 = number2;
        number2 = temp;     

        // Prompt the question 
        System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " - " + number2 + "? ");
        int answer = input.nextInt();


        if (number1 - number2 == answer) { // adding an opening brace here
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            correctCount++;

        } else { // adding an opening brace here
            System.out.println("Incorrect");
            incorrect++;
        }
        count++; 
      }
    }
    System.out.printf("You got %d correct and %d incorrect!\n", correctCount, incorrect); //Moving this outside the while loop
 } //closing braces for main
} //closing braces for class
```